# Creating ajax updated tabs in frontend in magento

Tags: php, jquery, magento-1.7

I want to create ajax updated tabs for user profile tab in frontend magento like categories tab in product management. I was use this code:

```
<ul id="page_tabs" class="tabs"> 
    <li>
        <a id="page_tabs_account" class="tab-item-link ajax active" href="http://localhost/magento/customer/account/" name="account">Account Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="page_tabs_account_edit" class="tab-item-link ajax notloaded" href="http://localhost/magento/customer/account/edit/" name="account_edit">Account Information</a>
   </li>
</ul>

<script>
    var FORM_KEY="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>";
    var varienGlobalEvents=false;
    page_tabsJsTabs = new varienTabs('page_tabs', 'tabcontainer', 'page_tabs_account',[]);
</script>
```

Also add js file in page.xml like:

```
 <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/tabs.js</script></action>
```

When we click on tab then ajax is call but return data is whole page data like with header, footer, left sidebar. We want only perticular tabs assigned `.phtml` file data (right sidebar).

So how we get that. If other method is easy then let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom controller that handles AJAX layouts.

Note that varienTabs will fetch the page set on your `href` links. Having `http://localhost/magento/customer/account/` on your tab links will make varienTabs just fetch the content at that URL.

Also, you will need special markup where the content will be posted. There should be a div which ID consists of the ID of your tab link ID + '_content'. E.g.:

```
<div id="page_tabs_account_content" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="page_tabs_account_edit_content" style="display: none;"></div>
```

**(Edit)** you would aso need the 'tabcontainer' div. It is the second parameter passed to the varienTabs function. Just wrap the divs above on it.